# I can't understand " do it in '', "come across", and " get something from" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Rumour has it that Smith and Wyatt aren't the best of friends. In fact, on the set they barely spoke to each other, though, this doesn't COME ACROSS in the film and they look like a great couple. *Happy as Larry* is a move away from the usual films Sonya makes - She is better known for roles in action films - but she has shown herself to be a capable comedy actress. However, I'm not sure this is the finest film to DO IT IN. Both men and women alike can GET SOMETHING FROM this film, but the romance angle is overplayed and the laughs are few and far between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In fact, on the set they barely spoke to each other, though, this doesn't COME ACROSS in the film and they look like a great couple

"Come across" refers to the act of the couple barely speaking to each other. The article states that even though they barely spoke to each other on the set, the same couldn't be inferred if one watched the film itself.

> However, I'm not sure this is the finest film to DO IT IN

"Do it in" refers to the actress being capable of doing comedy roles. The author of the article says that even though she has shown herself to be a capable comedy actress, Happy as Larry isn't the kind of film that reflects that talent of the actress.

> Both men and women alike can GET SOMETHING FROM this film, but the romance angle is overplayed and the laughs are few and far between.

"Get something from" refers to the lessons/messages the viewers can take away from the film. The article states that the film has elements that will appeal to both the men and the women viewers alike.

Comment: Thank you so much. very clear. It is DO IT IN not DO IN IT sorry :VV